# php onchange onload select

Tags: php, html, select

If I have an html form and select statement like,

```
<form method="post">
<select name="sortOrder" onchange="form.submit()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select></form>
```

and then a php switch statement which runs some stuff depending on the selection,

```
switch($_POST['sortOrder']){
case '1':
//execute this
break;
case '2':
//execute this
break;
case '3':
//execute this
break;
```

I want option 1 to load by default when the page loads.  Unfortunately when the page loads it doesn't display anything until I select an option and then it always defaults to option 1 so I can't ever execute an onchange select to option 1 either.  I tried incorporating the use of onload and onchange simultaneously but I think that's probably a poor way to do it, and it didn't work for me.  I have been searching but can't find an answer specific to mine.

Comment: write the code in `case 1` where your displaying the form.

Comment: The best way would be to create a blank option so then you always have to select either 1,2 or 3. I don't think it's good practice to default to '1' without including a submit button.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post">
<select name="sortOrder" onchange="form.submit()">
<option value="0">-</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select></form>
```

Php:

```
if(!isset($_POST['sortOrder']) {
 $sortOrder = 1;
} else {
 $sortOrder = $_POST['sortOrder'];
}
switch($sortOrder){
case '1':
//execute this
break;
case '2':
//execute this
break;
case '3':
//execute this
break;
```

So you tell PHP that the default is 1 if something selected use that select number so you don't need to use option value 0;

You want to load another page when you load this page?
Or you wanne put somestuff from 1 afther this from ?